# Can object keys in javascript cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, loops, memory-leaks, global-variables, object-literal

I can not provide code snippets as the code in question is classified. However, I will make my best attempt to clearly state the issue.

Our codebase has a Global Variable (Lets call it `"BIGGY"`) to which we add all our objects and the methods applicable to those objects.
So, I added an Object called `"Fish.Apple.Banana.Potato"` to `"BIGGY"`. I defined a method `"letsCall"` for `BIGGY["Fish.Apple.Banana.Potato"]`, and call it a `n` times, and I see that there is a memory leak (the process memory just shoots up over time).

However, if I change the name of `"Fish.Apple.Banana.Potato"` to `"Fish.Apple.Ban.Potato"`, there is no memory leak. No other change.

It can not be related to length of object keys as we have longer keys which do not cause this. I have read about some JS Engines not being optimised for long object keys, but can't find any references to any stability/memory leak issues caused by choice of object keys.

Has anybody seen this or knows how to fix this? Changing object identifiers until the problem disappears is not a good solution in my opinion.

Comment: How exactly are you checking for memory leaks? Are you certain that the tests are really comparing the same basic behavior? What you've described doesn't make much sense for a modern JavaScript engine. However, it's not at all impossible that the function you're calling is leaking memory due to its own behavior, whatever that is.

Comment: You can use heap snapshots in Chrome to check memory use.

Comment: Pointy, Thanks a lot. 
I was tracking the process in process explorer and charting Private Bytes which climbed by a fixed amount in each iteration. Although it does not mean memory leaks were happening for sure, but that is quite symptomatic, I thought.
I will check the heat snapshots in chrome and report if I see anything.

Comment: This seems absurd to me as well, but I can only see that changing the object keys fixes it. Will keep checking and write back if I find anything.

Comment: If you're using system tools, I think it's a good idea to start a completely fresh browser instance for each test. Using the in-browser tools would probably be better, but then again they might not catch some weird leaks that are really better thought of as runtime bugs.